# Combining URIs and Paths

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I am retro-fitting an application to make use of a PHP HTTP proxy (for caching) instead of the actual API server, the application currently combines the server URI and the path with the code:

```
methodUri = new Uri(apiUri, method.Path)
```

Where:

- **apiUri** = "http://api.eve-online.com/" (System.Uri Object)
- **method.Path** = "/char/SkillIntraining.xml.aspx" (string)

The result of the above statement is

```
"http://api.eve-online.com/char/SkillIntraining.xml.aspx" (System.Uri Object)
```

To use the PHP HTTP proxy the request would have to be changed as follows

- **apiUri** = "http://www.r-s.co.uk/eproxy.php" (System.Uri Object)
- **method.Path** = "/char/SkillIntraining.xml.aspx" (string)

The output I was expecting was:

```
"http://www.r-s.co.uk/eproxy.php/char/SkillIntraining.xml.aspx" (System.Uri Object)
```

However the output I get is:

```
"http://www.r-s.co.uk/char/SkillIntraining.xml.aspx" (System.Uri Object)
```

I understand that this is the correct functionality of the constructor Uri(Uri, string), my question is what would be a better function or constructor to use in its place to get the output I expect? I have tried removing the leading "/" in method.Path taking it from an absolute path to a relative path however that did not help.

***NOTE:*** both solutions below do work, however System.UriBuilder provides a more robust mechanism for combining URI's and paths and in my case resulted in fewer changes to resources than using System.Uri. Had I the choice I would mark both answers as correct.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Don't use the Uri object, use a [UriBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder.aspx) - it copes way better with missing slashes

So

```
Uri apiUri = new Uri("http://www.r-s.co.uk/eproxy.php");
string methodPath = "/char/SkillIntraining.xml.aspx";

System.UriBuilder uriBuilder = new System.UriBuilder(apiUri);
uriBuilder.Path += methodPath;

Console.WriteLine(uriBuilder.Uri.ToString());
```

works as expected and produces http://www.r-s.co.uk/eproxy.php/char/SkillIntraining.xml.aspx

Comment: You are correct System.UriBuilder is a more robust way of building URIs, thanks.

Comment: Note that the path will be URL encoded, so if it the addition contains a query string the ? and & characters will be encoded. This is a weakness in this method as described.

Comment: `UriBuilder` has a separate Query property for query strings, which is recommended as it handles character encoding correctly for that use case.

Comment: Exactly, I've gotten into the habit of parsing the UriBuilder.Query, adding query parameters, and then setting the builder query equal to the built NameValueCollection.

Answer (score 10):

Add a trailing "/" to apiUri, and remove the leading "/" from method.Path:

```
Uri apiUri = new Uri("http://www.r-s.co.uk/eproxy.php/");
string path = "char/SkillIntraining.xml.aspx";
Uri uri = new Uri(apiUri, path);
Console.WriteLine(uri.ToString());
```

Will print:

```
http://www.r-s.co.uk/eproxy.php/char/SkillIntraining.xml.aspx
```

Comment: Isn't there a tool, that would solve this issue of adding and subtracting "/" from one side or the other ?

Comment: If you put the leading slash on the bit you are adding, the Uri constructor thinks that it is relative to the base, so you get "http://www.base.com/bit-you-are-adding.html", if you leave off the leading slash it assumes it is relative to the original Uri, giving you "http://www.base.com/OriginalUri/bit-you-are-adding.html"