# How to redirect to https and also add www. in front of the link

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to redirect to https

I used the code below in Global.asax

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    if (!Context.Request.IsSecureConnection)
        Response.Redirect(Context.Request.Url.ToString().Replace("http:", "https:"));
}
```

but my problem is that I have to add www in front of link,
ie mywesite.se and after redirecting to https its like https://mywebsite.se but I want it like https://www.mywebsite.se

Comment: Could yo give me an example ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combining URIs and Paths](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/679171/combining-uris-and-paths)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go (write into web.config file)

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string lowerCaseURL = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().ToLower();
    if (lowerCaseURL.IndexOf("http://dotnetfunda.com") >= 0) // >=  because http starts from the 0 position : )
    {
        lowerCaseURL = lowerCaseURL.Replace("http://dotnetfunda.com", "https://www.dotnetfunda.com");

        HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 301;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("location", lowerCaseURL);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
}
```

Replace **dotnetfunda.com** to **yourwebsitedomainname.se**

Thanks

Comment: impFunctions ??

Comment: Sorry, it is just replace function. I will modify the code.

Answer (score 2):

Use [UriBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var url = Context.Request.Url;
var builder = new UriBuilder(url);
builder.Scheme = "https";
if (!url.Host.StartsWith("www"))
   builder.Host = "www." + url.Host;

Response.Redirect(builder.Uri);
```

Disclaimer: I didn't test this code.

Answer (score 2):

You can add rewrite rule in `web.config`

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <clear />
        <rule name="Redirect non-www OR non-https to https://www">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^mywebsite.se$" />
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.mywebsite.se/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent"/>
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Yeah this seems like better approach

Comment: You should first remove that you have written in `Global.asax`!

Comment: Can you add your full `stack trace` to the question.